# I am not able to find my kernel in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I can't find the desired environment in Visual Studio Code even though I have installed it in Anaconda.

When i click on "Select Kernel" in Visual Studio Code, it doesn't show my environment in the list. Before, I was able to see it, and I haven't changed particular options in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Ctrl+Shift+P** and choose the python intrepreter then set the kernel.

Read [document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/datascience/jupyter-notebooks#_setting-up-your-environment) for more details.